# Как подключиться к TelegramClient MTProxy

Tags: python-3.x, hex

```
server='To--Too--To.to--Too--to.tk'  
port=2590
secret='3fQ1mpsyX_HR5QhN8OD3U3s'
```

И пытаюсь подключиться:

```
client = TelegramClient(f"datas/{num['user']}",num['api_id'],num['api_hash'],
                connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate,
                proxy=(server, port, secret))
```

А ему не нравится:
MTProxy secret must be a hex-string representing 16 bytes